# Broken pipe error trying to run Android 3.1 ContactManager example in Eclipse 3.7?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, google-tv

I am getting this broken pipe error when I try to run one of the Example Projects for Android 3.1 Google TV (or any of the other example apps). I'm using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo, 64-bit JVM with 64-bit Ubuntu and Core2Quad, 8MB ram.  It launches my vm but the .apk wont deploy and I see this error in the Eclipse console:

```
[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddms]Created: [Debugger 8601-->1315 inactive]
[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddm-heap]Sending REAQ
[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddmlib]Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:72)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)

[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddms]Adding new client [Client pid: 1315]
[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddms]Closing [Client pid: 1315]
[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddms]broadcast 3: [Client pid: 1315]
[2011-12-11 20:41:28 - ddm-hello]Now disconnected: [Client pid: 1315]
```

NOTE: To get the vm to run faster I had to install qemu-kvm , kvm-intel , ia32-libs, and then 'sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv stop' .

I am able to deploy the Contact Manager using the command:

```
adb install ContactManager.apk
```

BUT, I am trying to figure out why Eclipse wasn't able to deploy it when I run my code from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google TV doesn't have a contact manager, so the sample isn't going to run well.

Comment: There is a group of about 20 different sample applications that comes with the Google TV SDK.  So, yes, there is one if you compile it.

Comment: Actually all that sample code is for Android.  Google TV doesn't have a Contacts Provider that your sample code would talk to.

Comment: Well, when I manually loaded the .apk, it ran, although it is buggy.  So, not sure if thats true.

Comment: Ok, well, in Eclipse, when I choose New Example Project-->3.1 , it give me a large list of example projects.   It didn't say that the example projects are for 3.1-non-TV , but apparently, they are?